# Arduino Check Battery Status when using

Tags: arduino

I tried to check my battery current status. I have 2 battery. 1st battery for Arduino and 2nd battery to my motors.

I used [this](http://www.electroschematics.com/9351/arduino-digital-voltmeter/) method, but it is not working. When I tried to check status my battery still using her, when checked with Multimeter I get `10.6V`, when I used this method I get for example `9.6V` or `11.5V`.
If I use hard I get `5v`, when I'm waiting 5 minutes I'm getting again for example `10v` and
it is not true.
The battery type is `NiCD 9.6V`.

How can I check it?

Answer (score 0):

The voltage divider method you linked to should work fine. I suspect that your problem is that you are using resistors with a very high tolerance. For example, if you built your divider using a pair of 1k resistors to measure the level of your 9.6V battery, you would expect to see 4.8V (or 1024.0*4.8/5.0) = 983 on your input pin - if your arduino is a 5.0V model.

This is not necessarily the case, however. If I take a pair of my 1k resistors and check them with a multimeter, I find that they are 980Ohm and 1009Ohm, respectively. Put an ohmmeter on your resistors (when they are disconnected from your circuit, preferably) and redo your ratios with the measurements you obtain. If I had:

```
G------NNNN------o-------NNNN------9.6V
        980      |       1009
                 |
                 Arduino input
```

...I would expect to read 1024.0 * 9.6 * 980/(980+1009) * 5 on the analog input pin, or 968.

If this isn't the case, please clarify your question and I'll see what I can do.